# Jet streams of black holes emit

Tags: black-hole

The speed of light is the upper limit at which conventional matter can travel. However, jet streams propel "material (...) at a significant fraction of the speed of light" (Wikipedia).

Let me rephrase the question, as I have made a mistake. Do we know what exactly emits the black hole in a jet stream?

And if they emit *something* than they put this matter back into this universe, which will then again serve as potential matter they could suck in.

Comment: "a significant fraction of the speed of light" is *less* than the speed of light. But maybe you're thinking that black hole jets come from inside the black hole. They don't.

Comment: Twice and embarrassed "oh" from my side, apologies. Thank you pointing that out. So where exactly do the jet streams come from?

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you so much! That answers it. Thanks!